# Qué es lo más óptimo, ejecutar los cálculos en SQL y leerlos en PHP, o leer los datos del SQL al PHP y hacer los calculos vía PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, optimización

Imaginemos que tengo un SGBD SQL Server con una tabla que se dedica a contar los huevos que se venden en un supermercado cada día:

Huevos_vendidos_al_dia

- id_fecha date PK
- num_huevos_vendido int

Y que quiero saber cuantos huevos se venden cada semana.

Cual de estas dos soluciones es la más óptima (en caso de que haya una diferente decirla también):

**1-** Creo el siguiente archivo .sql para que guarde en una tabla nueva los valores que quiero:

```
declare @huevos_semanal int;

select top 7 @huevos_semanal =sum(num_huevos_vendido) from Huevos_vendidos_al_dia order by id_fecha DESC
```

NOTA:*tendríamos la tabla huevos_semanales creada con las siguientes columnas*

- id_semana identity=ON PK int
- huevos_vendidos int

Fin NOTA

```
insert into huevos_semanales (huevos_vendidos) values (@huevos_semanal)
```

Y una vez guardado el valor de los huevos semanales en la tabla nueva, hacer una búsqueda mediante PHP para sacar el valor que quiero.

2-Con los valores que me da la tabla Huevos_vendidos_al_dia, hacer la operación en PHP

**php**

```
$suma_total = 0;
for($i=1;$i<=7;$i++){
 $sql_select="select top ".$i." num_huevos_vendido from Huevos_vendidos_al_dia order by id_fecha  DESC";
 $sql_result= sqlsrv_query($conn,sql_select);

 while($registro = sqlsrv_fetch_array(sql_result)){
  $matriz_dia[] = registro['num_huevos_vendido '];
 }
 $suma_total = suma_total + $matriz_dia[0]
}

echo "los huevos de esta semana han sido:".$suma_total ;
```

**?>**

NOTA: Los ejemplos los he hecho a ojo, no los he comprobado, pero no son importantes, lo importante es la duda del título

Gracias por leer

Salu2

Comment: Por lo que tengo entendido, cualquier operación en el select siempre será mas rápida que pasar los datos y luego hacerlo en el lenguaje de programación que sea. Fuente, mi experiencia y preguntas a dba's

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y por responder tan rápido, lo tendré en cuenta @rencinas

Comment: Como te comenta @rencinas, todo cálculo sobre datos almacenados en una DB serán más rápidos si los efectúas sobre el motor de BD que si los efectúas en el lenguaje de programación que consume a la BD. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta @MauricioContreras

Comment: Realmente dependerá de tu lógica y de tu necesidad. En este caso los cálculos son bastante sencillos, y será más rápido hacerlo en la consulta. Ahora bien, si tú cálculo fuera de una complejidad mayor, puede ser más óptimo dejar un proceso en background que te haga el cálculo y te lo devuelva, en lugar de ocupar complejidad en tu sgbd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es mucho más eficiente hacer los cálculos en la base de datos. Por lo general, hay 2 recursos que generan lentitud al consultar la base de datos: El disco y la red.

- La lectura desde disco siempre se va a realizar, a menos de que los datos estén en caché. En SQL Server, los datos se almacenan en páginas de 8KB, por lo que es la mínima cantidad de información que leerá al hacer una consulta. Si las páginas se quedan en caché, se hacen lecturas lógicas en vez de físicas y eso reduce el tiempo de ejecución. Por lo tanto, es probable que la lectura del dísco sea igual con ambos casos o puede haber múltiples lecturas físicas en el caso de ir recolectando fila por fila. En inglés, le llamamos RBAR (pronunciado Ribar) y es Row-By-Agonizing-Row (fila por fila agonizante).
- Por otro lado está la red, si pasas cada fila, la cantidad de información enviada será mayor. Si pasas sólo el resultado agrupado, la cantidad de información será menor y por lo tanto el envío se completará más rápido.

Por último, está el tiempo de procesamiento que rara vez es un problema (cuando el servidor está bien configurado). Puedes crear un código óptimo que aproveche de manera excelente los recursos del servidor de aplicación, o puedes usar los algoritmos que múltiples desarrolladores de Microsoft han optimizado a lo largo de los años para trabajar con grandes volúmenes de información.

Si gustas, podría tratar de incluir pruebas en esta respuesta, pero creo que todo debería de tener sentido por sí mismo.

Answer (score 0):

He estado realizando las pruebas con una tabla de 10.097 registros, considero que tiene un volumen suficiente para poder utilizarlo de referencia.

Estoy trabajando con SQLDeveloper 17.3.2.341 contra una bbdd Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

1. Lo que es el `select * from table` le ha costado 21.606 segundos
2. La siguiente prueba he añadido varias sumas/multiplicaciones entre los propios resultados le ha costado 21.706 segundos
   `select campo1*campo2, (campo3 - campo4) * campo5, tabla.* from tabla`
3. Ahora también he añadido modificaciones a varios campos de texto trim(), concat() etc... y el resultado ha sido de nuevo muy similar 21.813 segundos
    `select trim(campo1), lpad(campo2, 10, ' '), concat(campo3, campo4), tabla.* from tabla`
4. Realizando las dos anteriores pruebas combinadas si que se ha llegado a ver un leve aumento del tiempo llegando a 22.146 segundos.
5. Por otro lado, realizando una agrupación por un campo, el número de resultados ha sido menor lógicamente, a la par que el tiempo: 4.103 segundos.
   `select campo1 from tabla group by campo1;`
6. Por otro lado realizando operaciones sql como sum() avg() tan solo 4.647 segundos.
   `select campo1, sum(campo2) from tabla group by campo1;`

Por tanto en **RESUMEN** podríamos decir que las operaciones realizadas en el `select` de una consulta vagamente afectan al rendimiento de la misma.

*Todas las consultas las he ejecutado 5 veces para confirmar la integridad de los datos asegurándome en modificar registros de la consulta para evitar que los resultados estuvieran cacheados.

**Se que no es una respuesta a lo que se está preguntando exactamente, pero si que da cierta información para poder tener algo en lo que basarnos.

Comment: @Aprendiz Como por mi falta de conocimientos en php no podía hacer la comparativa entre filtrar los datos en php o en base de datos, lo que he hecho ha sido ver las diferencias entre filtrar en base de datos o no filtrar, y en ningún momento son dos motores de la base de datos, se utiliza la misma bbdd, tabla e IDE. Aunque por lo los votos, veo que varias personas están de acuerdo en que la respuesta es mala o al menos incompleta.